# Integration of different parts of code

Tags: java, ruby, code-reuse

I am working on a small project on metadata extraction from documents and have run into, eh a dilemma. I have some libraries in Java which work well with document-handling for information retrieval, like Apache Tika, POI etc and some more tools in other languages like Ruby(pdf-extract) and a script in bash to fetch data from a RESTful API using wget.

AFAIK, Code reuse is a good thing, right? But then, if its not possible (natively, I mean) to reuse all this code, What approach has to be taken?

Using Java to run terminal-commands is a solution but I don't think it is good programming practice.

Comment: Why do you say using Java to run terminal-commands is not a good programming practice?

Comment: There are no problems with using scripts to tie different programs together. The downside is that if you ever want to get your project work on another machine, you'll have to setup all the required programs again which may be tricky and/or complicated. But if you just want to get things done, that shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: @JosepValls If the same thing can be done in Java itself, wouldn't  it be better to do it in Java itself rather than using the script? (Just asking)

Comment: @mpkorstanje You are right, right now only one PC has all the dependencies installed and we are able to test the project holistically only there. pdf-extract especially takes a long time to get installed as it has a few other dependencies as well

Comment: @blumonkey one example I can think of is sorting or filtering large input files. Although its completely doable in Java, oftentimes using your OS natives commands will be much faster and memory efficient. I had an use case some years ago where my best solution was to just call a script that used a chain of sort and uniq calls as seen here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating multiple technologies is something that is very common in real world applications. In order for it to scale properly, you probably want to use some methodology to keep things consistent. To me, the weakest part is probably fetching using wget, but that's my opinion.

In order to integrate and for everything to scale nicely you may want to look at some message passing protocols and have some sort of handling of queues where individual workers run in different programming languages and environments. Look at:

- https://www.amqp.org/ (message passing standard)
- https://www.rabbitmq.com/ (Java, .NET, Ruby, Python, PHP, JavaScript...